# В чем отличие related_name от prefetch_related?

Tags: python, django

Я так понял, что при добавлении в модели связанных объектов через `ForeignKey` и `ManyToManyField` при помощи `related_name` можно обращаться из связанных объектов к тем, от которых эта связь была создана.

То есть, если допустим есть модель `Book` и модель `Author`, ссылка на `Author` это `ForeignKey` в модели `Book`, то тогда при установке у поля `ForeignKey` значение `related_name='books'` через `Author.books` можно будет посмотреть все книги, которые написал автор.

Немного непонятно, а для чего тогда нужен `prefetch_related`?

Мне всегда казалось, что именно `prefetch_related` выполняет эту задачу (находит все связанные объекты с текущим обратным соотношением), потому что такого функционала как `related_name` просто нет, но раз он есть, то для чего тогда `prefetch_related`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, вы правильно понимаете, что related_name используется для установления обратной связи между двумя моделями и позволяет обращаться к связанным объектам через объекты, на которые ссылаются эти объекты.

Но prefetch_related и related_name выполняют разные задачи.

prefetch_related используется для улучшения производительности запросов к базе данных, связанных с объектами модели, которые могут быть загружены заранее в память. Он выполняет предварительную загрузку связанных объектов, которые могут быть запрошены в будущем, и сохраняет их в кэше, чтобы избежать дополнительных запросов к базе данных при обращении к связанным объектам.

Когда вы используете related_name для установления обратной связи, это просто определяет имя, которое вы можете использовать для обращения к связанным объектам из других моделей. Но без prefetch_related каждый раз при обращении к связанным объектам будет выполняться отдельный запрос к базе данных.

Надеюсь стало яснее ^_^

Comment: Спасибо! То есть в принципе, можно даже накинуть `prefetch_related` на поле с именем `related_name`, когда к нему будут обращаться?

Comment: Да, вы можете использовать prefetch_related с полем, которое имеет related_name, чтобы улучшить производительность запросов к базе данных, связанных с этим полем.

Comment: chatGPT? Тогда вам сюда: [Почему публикация ответов, созданных GPT и ChatGPT, недопустима?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12247/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-gpt-%d0%b8-chatgpt-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Не знаю, почему мой ответ показался вам сгенерированным с помощью chatGPT. Но признаюсь заметить, что это весьма лестно:)